# When is rvalue destructor called / is this ok

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, destructor, rvalue

**Is the following wrapper class an "OK" way of keeping an intermediate object with `std::unique_ptr` to access the `me` member without copying `me`?**

Here is the example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

/* myobj from another library */
class myobj {
public:
    std::string me; /* actual member of interest is larger and more 
                       complicated. Don't want to copy of me or myobj */

    /* more members in actual class */

    myobj(std::string i_am) {
        /* more stuff happens in constructor */
        me = i_am;
    }

    ~myobj(){
        std::cout << me << ": Goodbye" << std::endl;
    }
};

/* A function in another library */
void who_is_this(std::string *who){
  std::cout << "This is " << *who << std::endl;
}

/* wrapper which I define */
class myobj_wrapper {
    using obj_ptr = std::unique_ptr<myobj>;
    obj_ptr ptr;

public:
    std::string *who;

    myobj_wrapper(std::string i_am): 
        ptr(new myobj(i_am)), who(&ptr.get()->me) {}

    myobj_wrapper(myobj &the_obj): who(&the_obj.me) { }
};

int main()
{
    {
        myobj bob("Bob");
        who_is_this(myobj_wrapper(bob).who); 
    }

    who_is_this(myobj_wrapper("Alice").who);

    return 0;
}
```

The resulting program yields

```
This is Bob
Bob: Goodbye
This is Alice
Alice: Goodbye
```

I define `myobj_wrapper` for multiple object to get the `who` pointer. What I am unsure of whether the object of interest (`std::string` in the above) will get destroyed before it is evaluated in the `who_is_this` function. **It does not seem to from the above but should I expect this? Are there pitfalls with the above solution?**

Comment: The code looks OK to me. Though I must admit I don't quite grasp the point of the exercise. I don't understand the problem this is supposedly a solution to.

Comment: What do you mean by **rvalue destructor**?

Comment: I mean the dynamically allocated object at `who_is_this(myobj_wrapper("Alice").who);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but here is my point of view:

```
who_is_this(myobj_wrapper("Alice").who);
```

This will create a wrapper object, that will take the string literal as its argument. Then, a `myobj` instance will be dynamically created, and handed over to a unique pointer. Via that instance, we get its data (the string), and make a traditional pointer from the wrapper class point to it. So, now `who` is pointing to `me`, i.e. Alice.

We pass `who` (which is a pointer) to:

```
void who_is_this(std::string *who)
```

which means that the function's parameter `who` is *not* a copy, but points to the original data.

So now the whole question is when the wrapper object will go out of scope (thus its data member (the unique pointer) will go out of scope too, meaning that the `myobj` instance which had been dynamically created will be garbage collected, which in turns means that `me` will go out of scope too, and so will `who`.

The wrapper object will go out of scope, after `who_is_this()` gets executed, which means that your code is OK.

Comment: "_The wrapper object will go out of scope, **after** `who_is_this()` gets executed, which means that your code is OK_" Cool, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thx. I figured someone might add a comment about a pitfall. I guess there is not any. The concrete example is [here](https://github.com/boennecd/dynamichazard/blob/master/src/problem_data.h) where I use the Armadillo library. See the `map_res` class and e.g., the `lp_map` methods. Sometimes a new `arma::vec` is needed while at other times there is no need to create a new object. (Disregard the comment above the class -- it is wrong).